# Undefined index error when trying to echo input text in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to echo the contents of an input field on enter. I have a text input field that I create here:

```
echo '<form id="changePassForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="changePass">
    <div class="changePassBtn">Change Password</div>
    <input class = "passwordText" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordText">
  </div>';
```

The field calls this javascript function correctly:

```
$(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){

    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        datatype: 'text',
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);

        }});    
     console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
});
```

Which references password change.php here:

```
<?php

session_start();
    echo "Hello world";

    $pass=$_POST['passwordText']; //name of input
    echo $pass;

/*$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sqlserver", 'username', 'password');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $checkforpass = "SELECT password FROM sqlserver.accounts WHERE username='".$username."'";*/

?>
```

I'm not versed in PHP but Hello world is output to console. How can I output/store value of text field in $pass?

Comment: Its working fine for me. I have tried on my local server. Where you facing error and can you please explain your issue.

Comment: Like in your last question you are creating your FormData object wrong `data: new FormData(this),` the keyword `this` refers to your password input element now, it still doesn't reference the form, `new FormData($("#changePassForm")[0])` will create your FormData object using the form element

Comment: @PatrickEvans See the fiddle in my answer to let me know if I've done anything wrong there. I think I've done everything correctly, but I get "false" logged to the console. TBH I've never used the FormData interface before. I've always just serialized things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, off the cuff:

```
$(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      var pass = $('#changePassForm input').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: 'passwordText=' + pass, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);

        }});    
     console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
});
```

---

Note also that it is `dataType:` not `datatype:`, and that dataType only affects returning data *not data being sent to PHP*

So, get it working simply first (as above), then get fancy with `$('#changePassForm').serialize()` etc.

Comment: Ah.. ok. Why do we need to precede pass with 'passwordText='?

Comment: If you use `.serialize()` it will build the key-value pairs for you, but in the above instance we're keeping it simple and building them ourselves. In the AJAX `data:` param, it is variable_name = value (so passwordText is the var name). Note on the PHP side that is also the variable name received as `$_POST['varname']`

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
$(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      var postData = $('#changePassForm').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: postData, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        datatype: 'text',
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);

        }});    
     console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
});
```

Comment: "Try this" type answers do not teach the user what is wrong or how to fix it, they just teach how to copy paste. Add a helpful description of what you changed and why. Also note you do not need the `processData` or `contentType` options anymore since `data` no longer uses a `FormData` object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `FormData`, you can see from [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) that the `FormData` object constructor takes an optional `<form>` element and you're using `this`, which refers to `$(".passwordText")`, which is a jQuery object. You can pass a form element by doing:

```
var form = document.getElementById("changePassForm");
var fd = new FormData(form);
```

Putting this all together we would then have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".passwordText").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = document.getElementById("changePassForm");
      var fd = new FormData(form);

      $.ajax({
        url: "../php/passwordchange.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: fd, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            console.log(data);

        }});    
       console.log("WORKS!!");   
    }
  });
});
```

As an alternative you can manually [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) any values you want to have sent in the ajax request like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).attr("value"));
```

---

### Disclaimer:

With that said, the FormData interface is only available in IE >= 10, so if you are worried about cross browser compatibility you may want to consider simply using jQuery's [serialize() method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to send the `data`. As an added bonus, it's only 1 line of code.:

```
data: $("#changePassForm").serialize()
```

Comment: The reason you got false for your `.has()` check is because you didn't pass in a form element: you have `document.getElementById("#changePassForm");` You tried to use a css selector with getElementById which takes only the id. So that was returning `null` and not the form element. Remove the `#` and the fiddle will work

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for noticing my typo. I've updated the answer.